# Automatically number results

Tags: php

#### I have this php function:

```
function GetByVotes(){
 $db = new Database;
 $db->query('SELECT posts.* FROM posts 
                      ORDER BY like_num DESC
                      LIMIT 10');
    $results = $db->resultset();
    return $results;
}
```

#### And this HTML:

```
<?php foreach(getByVotes() as $votes) :?>
        <div class="cerculet1">i</div><div class="celesMai"><a href="#" class="dece"><?php echo $votes->title;?></a></div>
     <?php endforeach;?>
```

#### Probem:

Now that the results are limited to 10, how do I make `i` from the`.cerculet1` div dynamic?

**Example:**

- 1 the first result
- 2 for the second
  ...
  etc
- 10 for the tenth

`.cerculet1` has nothing to do with the database, it's only a number that should increment as the number of result increment (from 1-10);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of your query are stored in an array, where the key begins at 0 and increments with each row. You can take advantage of simply adding `+1` to that key for what you display.

```
<?php foreach(getByVotes() as $k=>$votes) :?>
    <div class="cerculet1"><?= $k+1 ?></div>
    <div class="celesMai"><a href="#" class="dece"><?php echo $votes->title;?></a></div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @skrilled !

Answer (score 2):

No one will increment `$i` for you, so you have to do it yourself:

```
$i = 1;
foreach(getByVotes() as $votes) :?>
    <div class="cerculet1"><?=$i?></div><div class="celesMai"><a href="#" class="dece"><?php echo $votes->title;?></a></div>
<?php
     $i++;
endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I thought that is should be something simple, thanks a lot for the help!